# How backend function is called on search?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I'm working on one JSF application in which search functionality is implemented in one of the module. I tried to find out how this works but couldn't find anything relevant.

I've JSF code as below which has search component implemented.

```
    <h:panelGroup id="searchBarWrapper" styleClass="search-bar#{ciUser.patient ? ' search-no-filters' : ''}" layout="block">
        <h:inputText id="contentTextSearch" styleClass="form-control search" pt:data-loader="false"
                     value="#{contentView.freeText}"
                     pt:placeholder="#{uiBundle['content.search.placeholder']}"
                     pt:data-change-event="keydown:13,blur" pt:data-click-success=".open-level-one">
            <f:ajax event="change"
                    render="collaborative-#{contentView.side}:searchBarWrapper collaborative-#{contentView.side}:levelBack1 collaborative-#{contentView.side}:ColumnWideWrapper collaborative-#{contentView.side}:#{contentView.side}ColumnNarrow content-preview-component:content-preview"
                    onevent="JSF.ajaxOnEvent"/>
        </h:inputText>
        <a href="#search" class="search-submit">
            <i class="ico-search"></i>
        </a>
        <h:commandLink styleClass="btn btn-icon reset" rendered="#{not empty contentSession.freeText}"
                       pt:data-loader="false">
            <i class="ico-cross-circle reset"></i>
            <f:ajax listener="#{contentView.setFreeText(null)}"
                    render="collaborative-#{contentView.side}:searchBarWrapper collaborative-#{contentView.side}:#{contentView.side}ColumnWide collaborative-#{contentView.side}:#{contentView.side}ColumnNarrow"
                    onevent="JSF.ajaxOnEvent"/>
        </h:commandLink>
    </h:panelGroup>
```

`JSF.ajaxOnEvent` JS function is as below.

```
ajaxOnEvent: function (e) {
    if (e.status === 'begin') {
        $(e.source).addClass('processing');
    }
    JSF.handleClick(e);
    JSF.iFrameLoad(e);
    if (e.status === 'success') {
        $(e.source).removeClass('processing');
        CI.reInit(e);
    }
}
```

Let me know if any other information is required to identify the flow of search functionality. I'll be happy to share it.

Comment: There is ajax being used in your page and that normally plays an important role in doing all the work, but it looks like someone added an additional custom layer with passtrough attributes and a `JSF.handleClick(e); JSF.iFrameLoad(e)` that are sort of generically used (also on the button) and complicates things and are normally not needed for JSF (unless some other client-side ui layer is used like bootstrap or similar). So check what is additionally there and investigate (and btw, 3 upvotes in less then 4 hours is sort of remarkable, any co-workers that voted?)